# How to load different images in iOS from remote server

Tags: objective-c, ios

I wanna build a gallery, but the my problem is how to load the @2x images?

Will iOS try to search for them or i can specify the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this if/else block

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] &&
    ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)) {
  // Retina display
} else {
  // non-Retina display
}
```

You can detect whether you're on a retina display or standard display model and then load the correct image.

Comment: why not check for selector `scale`?, like `[[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]`

Comment: `scale` is a property, not a method. That's why.

Answer (score 1):

When you load the image From server.

Firstly You send request /Connection to Server that time you send imagesSize to server

Example:- www.example.com/iPhone/abc.php?imagesSize = 1

where ! for  @2x

0 for simple(means for non retina)

if you use this method then images not starch.

Answer (score 1):

you can store two versions of image, one for retina and one for non retina. when the device is about to download images from the web server, (assuming you are using webservice script)you can have a post data like:

```
NSString *postData;
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] &&
([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)) {
   postData = @"retina_device";
} else {
   postData = @"non_retina_device";
}
```

you will know what version of image the device is asking, assuming you will write webservice sript in php

```
 <?php
    $postData = $_REQUEST['postData'];
    if($postData == @"retina_device"){
       //return all images for retina device
    } 
 ?>
```